# Show that $\int_0^1 \left \lbrace (-1)^{\left \lceil \frac{1}{x} \right \rceil }\frac{1}{x} \right \rbrace \, {\rm d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Show that  $$\displaystyle{\int_0^1 \left \lbrace (-1)^{\left \lceil \frac{1}{x} \right \rceil }\frac{1}{x} \right \rbrace \, {\rm d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}}$$

**My try**

$$\displaystyle{\int\limits_0^1 {\left\{ {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{\left[ {1/x} \right]}}\frac{1}{x}} \right\}dx}  = \mathop  = \limits^{x \to 1/x}  = \int\limits_1^\infty  {\left\{ {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{\left[ x \right]}}x} \right\}\frac{1}{{{x^2}}}dx}  = }$$ $$\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( {\int\limits_{2n - 1}^{2n} {\left\{ {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{\left[ x \right]}}x} \right\}\frac{1}{{{x^2}}}dx}  + \int\limits_{2n}^{2n + 1} {\left\{ {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{\left[ x \right]}}x} \right\}\frac{1}{{{x^2}}}dx} } \right)}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( {\int\limits_{2n - 1}^{2n} {\left\{ { - x} \right\}\frac{1}{{{x^2}}}dx}  + \int\limits_{2n}^{2n + 1} {\left\{ x \right\}\frac{1}{{{x^2}}}dx} } \right)}  = }$$ $$\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( {\int\limits_{2n - 1}^{2n} {\left( {1 - \left\{ x \right\}} \right)\frac{1}{{{x^2}}}dx}  + \int\limits_{2n}^{2n + 1} {\left\{ x \right\}\frac{1}{{{x^2}}}dx} } \right)}}$$

I'm not sure about the closed form; my friends say it's either $\log\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, $1 - \log\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, or $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For this kind of problem, it helps to cut the integral wrt to interval wher the ceiling function is constant, to get rid of it. Then sum the series. I'm not sure you need a change of variable though.

Comment: I agree with your approach, although for readability I'd suggest changing the names of the dummy variables in your integrals when you make a substitution. I get the value to be $\log\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever we do, the ceiling function is going to cause difficulties with the integration at some point (as it's discontinuous). So let's start by doing something about that. Let $N$ be a positive integer and $y=\frac{1}{x}$, and define
$$I_N=\int_\frac{1}{2N+1}^1 \left \lbrace (-1)^{\left \lceil \frac{1}{x} \right \rceil }\frac{1}{x} \right \rbrace dx = \int_1^{2N+1} \frac{1}{y^2}\left \lbrace (-1)^{\left \lceil y \right \rceil }y \right \rbrace dy $$

Now we can get rid of the ceiling function and the power of $-1$ by considering cases when $2n-1< y \le 2n$ and when $2n< y\le 2n+1$:

$$\begin{align*}I_N&=\sum_{n=1}^N \left[ \int_{2n-1}^{2n} \frac{1}{y^2}\left \lbrace (-1)^{\left \lceil y \right \rceil }y \right \rbrace dy + \int_{2n}^{2n+1} \frac{1}{y^2}\left \lbrace (-1)^{\left \lceil y \right \rceil }y \right \rbrace dy \right] \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N \left[ \int_{2n-1}^{2n} \frac{1}{y^2}\left \lbrace y \right \rbrace dy + \int_{2n}^{2n+1} \frac{1}{y^2}\left \lbrace -y \right \rbrace dy \right] \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N \left[ \int_{2n-1}^{2n} \frac{1}{y^2}\left \lbrace y \right \rbrace dy + \int_{2n}^{2n+1} \frac{1}{y^2}\left \lbrace 1-y \right \rbrace dy \right]
\end{align*}$$

Now, with the substitution $u=y-(2n-1)$,
$$\int_{2n-1}^{2n} \frac{1}{y^2}\left \lbrace y \right \rbrace dy = \int_0^1 \frac{u}{(u+2n-1)^2} du=\log\frac{2n}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}$$

and with $v=y-2n$,
$$\int_{2n}^{2n+1} \frac{1}{y^2}\left \lbrace 1-y \right \rbrace dy =\int_0^1 \frac{1-v}{(v+2n)^2} dv=\log\frac{2n}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n}$$

so that
$$\begin{align*}
I_N&=\sum_{n=1}^N \left[\log\frac{2n}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n} + \log\frac{2n}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n}\right] \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N \log\frac{4n^2}{4n^2-1}
\end{align*}$$

Letting $N\to \infty$, this is the logarithm of the well-known Wallis product formula for $\frac{\pi}{2}$; so the value of the original integral is $\boxed{\log\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be careful about performing substitutions before converting the integrand into a sum.  Let $$f(x) = \left\{\frac{(-1)^{\lceil 1/x \rceil}}{x}\right\},$$
where as usual $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.  Then on each interval $x \in [\frac{1}{k+1}, \frac{1}{k})$ for $k \in \mathbb Z^+$, we have $k < \frac{1}{x} \le k+1$ hence $\lceil \frac{1}{x} \rceil = k+1$; thus when $k$ is odd, $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} - k$, and when $k$ is even, $f(x) = k+1 - \frac{1}{x}$.  Consequently,

$$\begin{align}
\int_{x=0}^1 f(x) \, dx 
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{x=1/(k+1)}^{1/k} f(x) \, dx \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left( \int_{x=1/(2m)}^{1/(2m-1)} \frac{1}{x} - (2m-1) \, dx + \int_{x=1/(2m+1)}^{1/(2m)} 2m + 1 - \frac{1}{x} \, dx \right) \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left( \log \frac{2m}{2m-1} - \frac{1}{2m} + \frac{1}{2m} - \log \frac{2m+1}{2m}\right) \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \log \frac{4m^2}{4m^2-1} \\
&= \log \prod_{m=1}^\infty \frac{4m^2}{4m^2-1} \\
&= \log \frac{\pi}{2} \approx 0.451583 \ldots.
\end{align}$$

where in the penultimate step we recognize the infinite product as the familiar [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).

A straightforward argument as to why the value of the integral cannot be $\pi/2$ is that on $x \in (0,1]$, we clearly have $0 \le f \le 1$, thus its integral is bounded above by $1$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\left \{ (-1)^{\left \lfloor 1/x \right \rfloor} \frac{1}{x} \right \}\, {\rm d}x &\overset{u=1/x}{=\! =\! =\!} \int_{1}^{\infty} \left \{ (-1)^{\left \lfloor x  \right \rfloor} x \right \} \frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2}  \\ 
 &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \int_{2n-1}^{2n} \left \{ (-1)^{\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor} x \right \} \frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2}  + \int_{2n}^{2n+1} \left \{ (-1)^{\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor} x \right \} \frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2} \right]\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [ \int_{2n-1}^{2n} \frac{\left \{ -x \right \}}{x^2}\, {\rm d}x  + \int_{2n}^{2n+1} \frac{\left \{ x \right \}}{x^2} \, {\rm d}x  \right ]\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [ \int_{2n-1}^{2n} \frac{1-\left \{ x \right \}}{x^2} \, {\rm d}x+ \int_{2n}^{2n+1} \frac{\left \{ x \right \}}{x^2} \, {\rm d}x \right ]\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{2n-1}^{2n} \frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [ \int_{2n-1}^{2n} \left ( x-2n+1 \right )\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2} - \int_{2n}^{2n+1} (x-2n) \frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2} \right ]\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [ \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n} \right ] - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [ \int_{2n-1}^{2n}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x} - (2n-1) \int_{2n-1}^{2n}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2} - \int_{2n}^{2n+1} \frac{{\rm d}x}{x} +2n \int_{2n}^{2n+1} \frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2} \right ]\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [ \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n} \right ] - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [ \log \frac{4n^2}{(2n-1)(2n+1)} - \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n+1} \right ] \\
 &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left [ \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n} \right ] + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [ \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n+1} \right ] - \log \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( 1+ \frac{1}{4n^2-1} \right ) \\
&=\cancel{\log 2- \log 2} +1- \log \frac{\pi}{2} \\
&=1- \log \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align*}

because

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [ \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n} \right ] &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} 1^n}{n}\\ 
 &=  \log (1+1) \\
 &=\log 2
\end{align*}

and similarly the second sum. Now that product is actually very famous but if we want a proof we are using the Stirling approximation of

\begin{equation} n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \left ( \frac{n}{e} \right )^n \end{equation}

thus:

\begin{align*}
\log \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( 1+ \frac{1}{4n^2-1} \right )  &=\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \log \frac{4^n (n!)^2 }{1\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdots (2n-1)^2\cdot (2n+1)} \\ 
 &= \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \log \frac{4^{2n} (n!)^4}{\left ( (2n)! \right)^2 \left ( 2n+1 \right )}\\ 
 &\overset{(1)}{=} \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \log \frac{4^{2n} (2\pi n)^2 \left ( \frac{n}{e} \right )^{4n}}{(4\pi n) \left ( \frac{2n}{e} \right )^{4n} (2n+1)}\\ 
 &= \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \log \frac{\left ( 2\pi n \right )^2}{(4\pi n) (2n+1)} \\
 &=\log \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align*}